# How to properly block the interface in AngularJS while data is loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my form there are many fields where the data is loaded from server, there are also a dependent data lists and while performs the data loading I want to
freeze interface - for example, by showing the progress bar. A layer with a large `z-index`, which would be over all others and the progress-bar in the corner. For example..

I know how to do it by using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) or [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home):

- [Modal window with progressbar for long tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201247/modal-window-with-progressbar-for-long-tasks)

How to do it by using AngularJS? Basically, I know how to do it by using JavaScript.

The problem is quite common.. Maybe there are ready solutions?

Comment: When you say data loading, do you mean loading it from server ??

Comment: Try [this](http://juristr.com/blog/2013/12/nprogress-splash-screen/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option to integrate into your solution is [promise tracker](https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker/blob/master/README.md)

If you need to block out the screen while your application bootstraps [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) allows you to display a message while angular is initializing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the angular $http to load your data you can easily use this directive to show a loading screen or progress bar:

https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy